# Remove selection Flexgrid or change the co

Tags: vb.net

I have a flexgrid that I'm forced to use. Thing is that when i add new items the last row gets highligthed. I want to disable the selection I have tried this but is does not work.

```
   with flexgrid1

   .rowsel = .row
   .colsel = .col

   end with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
grid.rowsel = -1
```